# Unable to Browse Shapefiles(Creating store) from my local folder while using Geoserver 2.22.2

Tags: java, shapefile, geoserver

I am using Geoserver version 2.22.2 with Java JDK 19.0.2
Trying to create New work store for vector data source SHAPEFILE but unable to browse it.
After Clicking on Browse it is not able to load my local folders.

I have put both Geoserver and Java JDK folder in Programme Files also, I have set the Environmental Variable. Unable to get what is going Wrong. Why I am not able to Browse the shapefile.

Comment: Which user is running GeoServer? How did you install it?

Comment: I had downloaded the Platform Independent Binary installation. After installing, I started GeoServer by running C:\Program Files\geoserver-2.22.2\bin\startup.bat and then opening http://localhost:8080/geoserver in a browser and am logged in as admin.

Comment: Try with java 11

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes. Now It is Working with JAVA 11